# How to send an integer from ajax without jquery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I am trying to send an integer called 'petadid' from this js to the django view called 'petadlikeview'. But it looks like the data is not going there in the view.If i print 'petadid' in the view, it shows 'None'. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong? I am new to ajax and django.

Here is my js:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(argument) {
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
var element = document.getElementById("likes");
var petadid = $(this).attr("data-petadid");
element.addEventListener("click",function(){
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST",'/petadlike/')
  req.onload = function(){
    console.log(req.responseText);
    console.log(petadid);
    var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
  }
  req.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", '{{ csrf_token }}');
  var data = {
    'petadid':petadid,
  }
  req.send(data);
});
});
</script>
```

And here is my django-view:

```
def petadlikeview(request):
print("vau")
if request.method=="POST":
    print("vai")
    petadid = request.POST.get('petadid')
    print(petadid)
    petad = PetAd.objects.get(pk=petadid)
    like_count = petad.petadlikes_set.all().count()
    like, created = petadlikes.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user,petad=petad)
    print(created)
    if created is False:
        petadlikes.objects.get(user=request.user,petad=petad).delete()
        like_count -= 1
        liked = False
    else:
        like.save()
        like_count += 1
        liked = True
    dict = {'like_count':like_count}
    return JsonResponse(dict)
    return HttpResponse(str(like_count)+' people have liked this')
else:
    return HttpResponse('Bad Request')
```

Comment: Why are you willing to use jQuery for `.attr()` but not for the AJAX call, even though that's the more complicated part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest will not automatically convert an object to POST data as jQuery does, you need to create the URL-encoded string yourself.

```
var data = "petadid=" + encodeURIComponent(petadid);
```

Also

```
var petadid = $(this).attr("data-petadid");
```

should probably be

```
var petadid = $(element).attr("data-petadid");
```